# Keep Dependencies Private in Public iOS Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm currently building a framework in Swift for public distribution. Let's call it `PublicFramework`.

I want to include a private pod containing a number of extensions and protocols that I use across many of my projects which we can call `PrivateUtilsPod`.

In `PrivateUtilsPod`, all of my extensions/protocols are marked `public` so I can reuse them in whatever app I'm building, but since I'm now trying to include this pod in a framework, I don't want to expose anything from `PrivateUtilsPod` to `PublicFramework`'s client.

Is there a way for me to completely encapsulate the existence `PrivateUtilsPod` within my `PublicFramework`? I know I could just copy the source files over, and change the access modifiers to `internal`, but that would defeat the purpose of `PrivateUtilsPod`.

Is there another way I should be approaching this problem?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use the public methods of a framework you included in your `PublicFramework`, or is there something special with CocoaPods?

Comment: Why exactly is it a problem that `PrivateUtilsPod` would be exposed by someone who pulls in `PublicFramework`?

Comment: @SilvanMosberger - Unless I make the entire framework statically linked, the client will need to include PrivateUtilsPod in their project to successfully compile PublicFramework. If my helper utils in PrivateUtilsPod are marked public (which they need to be for use in PublicFramework), nothing keeps the client from using them.

Comment: @nhgrif - I'm trying to minimize the public "surface area" of my framework. If you expose it, clients will try and use it and find a way to abuse it.